# I would like to but I can’t turn off my upstairs heat at the breaker without turning of part of downstairs

Tags: electrical-panel

I can’t turn heat off upstairs because two of my downstairs baseboards are on the same breaker. Upstairs Thermostat controls upstairs baseboards and downstairs thermostat controls all downstairs baseboards including the ones on the upstairs breaker.
Upstairs plus 2 baseboards are on a double breaker. Downstairs two remaining baseboards are on a single breaker.
Not sure about the thermostats.
Breaker box is not labeled properly.

Comment: Pictures of the panel and baseboards will help.  Do you know if the heaters are on 120 volt circuit or 240 volt circuit?  It sounds like they might be 120v because of the single breaker, if so then maybe just need to replace the double breaker with two singles.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Why do you want to turn off the breaker?  If you want to turn off the upstairs heat just turn the upstairs stat all the way down.  If you're doing maintenance and want to cut power, just turn everything off.   Otherwise tell us the objective and the problem.

Comment: @jay613  gotta agree...why can't they turn the thermostat all the way down?  If they want to permanently disconnect the upper floor's heaters, just pull the t-stat remove in incoming hots, cap them safely.  Like jay said, "what are you trying to accomplish?"  This is just my opinion, but with the rapidly rising electrical rates, resistance heating is the most expensive and will just get worse.   If practical for your house, have you considered a mini-split heat pump?   They are very efficient and you get the added benefit of Air Conditioning.

Comment: It's time to start tracing some wires and seeing if you can bypass some thermostats and add thermostats to others

Comment: Please take the [tour] to see how this site is a bit different than others. This is specifically a _question_ and answer board. If you don't ask a question, we can't provide an answer. Please feel free to [edit] your question to tell us what is you'd like to have answered.

Answer (score 4):

What you're describing sounds perfectly normal.  A typical 20 amp heater circuit can support 3840 watts (13,000 BTU) of heaters, and individual wall units are anywhere from 500 to 2000 watts.  it would be a waste of wire to give each heater or thermostat a dedicated circuit.

If you're doing maintenance on the heater or thermostat, shut the main breaker off, do your work and turn the power back on.  If you just want to *stop heating the room* for now,  set the thermostat knob all the way to the left.  If you feel a detent, that means you've hit a "hard off" and it won't turn on no matter how cold it gets.  This might be a mistake if you're in freeze country.

If you're eliminating the heater altogether, then the wires which will now be coming out of the walls need to be handled in some way. Do not cut them off, and do not sacrifice any length - you might want it someday!  I can't tell you how many questions we get of "Hi, I keep tripping breakers in this room because of the loads in here. Is there any way I can get another circuit run to this room somehow?" Or "I need a 240V circuit for a tool, exercise equipment etc." Be a crying shame *to have had one, and destroyed it needlessly*.

Anyway, the right way is to install a metal junction box over top of the hole the wires are coming into.  Grounds should be wired to the metal box, the other wires are capped off as needed.

It's possible to abandon a cable and cut the wires off, however it's absolutely required to find the other end of that cable, positively identify it, and utterly destroy both ends (any part that is reachable) so it can never be used again. This must be done carefully - it would be very dangerous for a cut-off wire being re-energized by someone reconnecting a wire (at the other end) that they see loose.  (they have a totally unrelated problem, are trying to fix that problem, and 'try things').